# É possível desabilitar determinada ação de um elemento HTML com determinada classe via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-blockui, jquery-ui-multiselect

Na minha inicialização eu seto que todos os links devem bloquear, usando o plugin [jquery-blockui](/questions/tagged/jquery-blockui), a tela para evitar os múltiplos cliques do usuário impaciente evitando múltiplas e desnecessárias requisições ao servidor.

```
$("a").on("click", $.blockUI);
```

Tive um problema que relatei na pergunta [Renderização de select múltiplo diferente para cada browser](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6772/renderizacao-de-select-multiplo-diferente-para-cada-browser) e acabei aceitando como resposta e a única resposta dada e utilizando a solução dada na primeira opção do update desta mesma resposta, porém este widget usa links para marcar todas as opções, desmarcar todas as opções ou fechá-lo e isso dispara meu evento acima. Tentei utilizar para parar o evento o código abaixo:

```
$("a.ui-multiselect-none, a.ui-multiselect-all, a.ui-multiselect-close").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Ou seja, tentei parar a ação padrão do link nos links com as classes utilizadas pelo widget, porém isso não funcionou. O que efetivamente funcionou foi o que utilizei abaixo:

```
$("a.ui-multiselect-none, a.ui-multiselect-all, a.ui-multiselect-close").on("click", $.unblockUI);
```

Porém esta solução dá um efeito na tela de como se ela tivesse piscando. Existe algum jeito de fazer com que estes links simplesmente não acionem o blockUI de forma diferente dos demais sendo uma exceção de UX do sistema?

Comment: Já tentou `e.preventDefault()` e logo depois um `return(false)`?

Comment: Já viu esta pergunta e a solução `pointer-events: none;` ?: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2352/como-impedir-um-click-sobre-um-link-ancora-ou-elemento-com-evento-amarrado/2353#2353

Comment: Sergio, o browser homologado é o IE 8. Além disso eu não teria como adicionar essas classes ao widget.

Comment: @PauloRoberto, sua alternativa também não funcionou, porém obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @Zuul já consegui a solução e postei aqui, obrigado pelo seu tempo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resposta seria não atrelar o evento aos links como abaixo:

```
$("a:not(.ui-multiselect-none, .ui-multiselect-all, .ui-multiselect-close)").on("click", $.blockUI);
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944117/can-you-disable-override-certain-action-of-an-html-element-with-given-class-via/21944261#21944261

Answer (score 0):

Você retornando um valor falso irá prevenir a opção padrão do link e de outros eventos também:

```
$("a.ui-multiselect-none, a.ui-multiselect-all, a.ui-multiselect-close").on("click", function(e) {
    return false;
});
```

Porém caso queira evitar somente a ação de outros eventos, mantendo a ação padrão do link use isso:

```
$("a.ui-multiselect-none, a.ui-multiselect-all, a.ui-multiselect-close").on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Ainda, pode ocorrer, dependendo da maneira que seu código está organizado, que a função acima não impeça que a ação padrão do link seja desativada por outras funções.
Nesse caso use a primeira opção, com uma alteração: antes do `return false` simule a ação padrão do link com `window.location.replace(this.href);`.

Ainda, uma última alternativa:

```
$("a").on("click", function () {
  var classes = 'ui-multiselect-none ui-multiselect-all ui-multiselect-close'.split(' ');
  while (classes.length) {
    if (this.hasClass(classes.pop())) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  $.blockUI();
});
```

Comment: obrigado pelo seu tempo, mas suas alternativas também não funcionaram, o bloqueio de tela continua ocorrendo.